# VSO Update Build definition - already exists

Tags: azure-pipelines, azure-devops-rest-api

I'm using the Visual Studio Online rest api, and trying to update an existing build definition

So according to the documentation at:
https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/integrate/api/build/definitions#Updateabuilddefinition

It says you can update an existing build definition.

So I feed the following JSON to the post:

```
    { 
      id: 43,
      name: 'Test Build',
      revision: 10,
      variables: { 
        version: { value: '20', allowOverride: true } 
      },
      comment: 'New version added: 20' 
    }
```

So the id and revision are the same as the existing build definition.

It fails with the following error:

```
    {
        "$id":"1",
        "innerException":null,
        "message":"Build definition Test Build already exists for project TestProject.",
        "typeName":"Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.WebApi.DefinitionExistsException, Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build2.WebApi, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a",
        "typeKey":"DefinitionExistsException",
        "errorCode":0,
        "eventId":3000
    }
```

Any ideas what I'm doing incorrect?

Answer (score 1):

If you see the error 'message=Build definition TestingBuild already exists for project MyProj.' It may be that your powershell has '-Method Post' where it should have '-Method PUT'

Answer (score 0):

Fiddler to the rescue!

What I was trying to do was trigger a build, with variables. Previous questions on this pointed to the only way was to update the build definition.

You don't have to. When you queue a build, you can send in values for the variables in your build definition.

So queue a build, using the API at:
https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/integrate/api/build/builds#Queueabuild

Send in the following into the body of the post:

```
    { 
        queue: { id: 5 },
        definition: { id: 43 },
        project: { id: 'aaa12345-a1b2-1a23-123a-1234a56789ab' },
        parameters: '{"version":"20"}',
        reason: 1,
        demands: [] 
    }
```

Notice the following:

1. It is called parameters, not variables;
2. It is a string sent in, not json elements. So in my nodejs its mocked up as:

   ```
   parameters:"{\"version\":\"" + version + "\"}"
   ```

Now you can queue a build, and provide values to your variables through the API